# SQL query to find maximum of 3 transactions after the specific part repair

Tags: sql, teradata

My data is similiar to this example which is very huge so idealy require an efficient code. I want to find those transactions(max of 3) after the charger repair.

```
TRANSACTION_ID  REPAIR_DATE CUSTOMER_ID    COMPONENT   LABOR_CODE_DESC ....
28289           6/25/2015   AH123        LAPTOP       CHARGER REPAIR
28235           6/29/2015    AH123       LAPTOP         CHIP REPLACE
258978         6/27/2013      HW687      PHONE      TOUCH SCREEN
28223           6/2/2014     AH123       LAPTOP      BATTERY REPAIR
215678          9/7/2014       HW687      PHONE         SIM REPAIR
527808          7/30/2016      HW687      LAPTOP         BATTERY REPAIR
567976          7/28/2014      HW687      LAPTOP         CHARGER REPAIR
7678698         8/68/2015     AH123        LAPTOP        BATTERY REPAIR
9987908          5/7/2006       TU890       PHONE         SIM REPAIR
.....


OUTPUT
TRANSACTION_ID  REPAIR_DATE CUSTOMER_ID COMPONENT    LABOR_CODE_DESC ....
28235           6/29/2015    AH123       LAPTOP         CHIP REPLACE
7678698         8/68/2015      AH123        LAPTOP        BATTERY REPAIR
527808          7/30/2016     HW687      LAPTOP          BATTERY REPAIR
215678          9/7/2014       HW687      PHONE     SIM REPAIR

.....
```

SO all I want is those customer id transactions which have had charger repair and a maximum of 3 transactions after the charger repair date

```
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID, REPAIR_DATE,CUSTOMER_ID,LABOR_CODE_DESC from table 
where customer_id IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID from table where LABOR_CODE_DESC 
like '%CHARGER REPAIR%')
```

Not sure how I can expand to get maximum of 3 transactions after CHARGER REPAIR

Comment: Simply add limit 3 at the end of your query

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using teradata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the three rows after a charger repair date:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY 
   -- check if any of the three previous rows contains 'CHARGER REPAIR'
   Max(CASE WHEN LABOR_CODE_DESC = 'CHARGER REPAIR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   Over (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
         ORDER BY REPAIR_DATE
         ROWS BETWEEN 3 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) = 1
```

Edit:

To get only rows with a repair date within the next 10 days:

```
   -- check if any of the previous rows contains 'CHARGER REPAIR'
   -- and the current REPAIR_DATE is within 10 days after that repair
   Max(CASE WHEN LABOR_CODE_DESC = 'CHARGER REPAIR' THEN REPAIR_DATE END)
   Over (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID
         ORDER BY REPAIR_DATE
         ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) >= REPAIR_DATE - 10
```

Comment: how do I add if I require transactions only after 10 days of repair_date of 'Charger Repair'. Thought of using + INTERVAL '10' day but not sure how and where to include the condition

Comment: :If I have multiple transactions on the same day as CHARGER REPAIR. Few of them appear and few don't as we are ordering them according to the REPAIR_DATE. How do I change to not show any transactions on the same day as CHARGER REPAIR to avoid this ( may be adding a day after CHARGER REPAIR date)?

Comment: How do I overcome the multiple Transactions on the same day as charger repair? I might even like to eliminate all the transactions that happen on the same day as charger Repair. Is it possible by changing this code a little

Answer (score -1):

You can get all such transactions by doing:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.repair_date > (select t2.repair_date
                       from table t2
                       where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id and
                             labor_code_desc like '%CHARGER REPAIR%'
                      );
```

Limiting this to 3 per customer is a little tricker, but you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by repair_date) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when labor_code_desc like '%CHARGER REPAIR%' then repair_date end) over (partition by customer_id) as max_crd
            from table t
           ) t
      where t.repair_date > max_crd
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3707 : 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a 'SUCCEEDS' keyword or a 'MEETS' keyword or a 'PRECEDES' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a 'CONTAINS' keyword between the word 'repair_date' and ')'. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.020 
 
STATEMENT 1: Unknown failed.

Comment: @viji . . . I assume that was for the second query.  I didn't finish the `where` clause.

Comment: Got this error now-Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5479 : HY000] Ordered Analytical Functions not allowed in WHERE Clause. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.026 
 
STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.

Comment: @viji . . . There is no ordered analytic function in a `where` clause.  In Teradata, however, you can put them into the `qualify` clause instead.